# Dont select data from database with two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables sale and receipt.Table structure and result structure is shown below.

sale

```
date          total     sale_type

15-8-2014      50       credit

16-8-2014      100      credit

17-8-201       200      return

18-8-2014      300      return
```

receipt

```
  date           net_amount


  15-8-2014         100

  16-8-2014         200

  17-8-2014         300
```

result

```
date            sale      receipt


15-8-2014       50         100

16-8-2014       100        200

17 -8-2014      200        300

18-8-2014       300
```

Using my query i got these result structure ,but i want to get also the sum total in the case sale_type='credit' and sale_type='return".Any body help me?

My query is

```
    select date,total,net_amount from
     (select  date, total, null as net_amount, 2 as sort_col from sale union
all select date, 
null as total, net_amount as net_amount, 1 as sort_col from receipt)
 as a order by date desc, sort_col desc
```

Comment: Post your expected result set

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query (using `JOIN` and `CASE` get you expected results?

```
SELECT
    s.date,
    s.total AS sale,
    r.net_amount AS receipt,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN s.sale_type = 'credit' THEN s.total
        ELSE 0
    END) AS sum_credit,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN s.sale_type = 'return' THEN s.total
        ELSE 0
    END) AS sum_return
FROM sale s
LEFT JOIN receipt r
ON s.date = r.date
GROUP BY s.date, s.total, r.net_amount;
```